# login failed while accessing the Active directory with logon name from WSO2 apim

Tags: active-directory, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I've connected my WSO2 api manager with external ldap i.e. Microsoft Active Directory.

I have a following `user` in my Active directory :

`Username : WSO2 Admin
User logon Name : WSO2.Admin@india.test.com
NT logon Name : INDIA\WSO2.Admin`

When I'm setting the `Admin role` for my user's `Username` in user-mgt.xml file. I'm able to login into the the WSO2 admin console with Username i.e. `WSO2 Admin` only and I'm also able to see all the users from active directory but If I'm trying to login into management console with the actual logon name i.e. `india\WSO2.Admin` or `WSO2.Admin@india.test.com` It's showing me `login failed` error.

`<AdminUser>
     <UserName>WSO2 Admin</UserName>
     <Password>xxxxx</Password>
</AdminUser>`

Can somebody please help me solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2 carbon (base for all wso2 products, not just apim) realms and domains are having different meaning.

e. g. the domain `@india.test.com` in the carbon logon form denotes the tenant (the default tenant is `carbon.super`. You may try to log in with `WSO2.Admin@carbon.super` in theory it should work. (I did not try it myself)

as well the realm (in form of `realm\username`) hints the carbon to use a secondary userstore with specified realm parameter (I may be wrong in this format, if someone knows for sure, feel welcome to correct me)

I believe full domain should work with a Kerberos authenticator (used for applications, not for the Carbon management console), but this authenticator has been reworked and improved in current versions, so I don't know current state)